# Looping within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to shorten my coding and I am having a problem here.

I have this very long array list

```
array(stackoverflow1,
stackoverflow2,
stackoverflow3,
stackoverflow4,
stackoverflow5,
stackoverflow6........stackoverflow100);
```

I tried to do something like this

```
array (
for ($i = 1; $i<100; $i++)
{"stackoverflow".$i,}
);
```

I tried many ways to clear the syntax error, it just does not work. Is there a way to create a loop within a array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do what you're trying to do. That is completely unsupported syntax. You cannot mix executable code with array declarations.

You can, however, declare an empty array, and append items to it:

```
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; ++$i) {
  $item[] = "stackoverflow$i";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $arr = array();

    for($i=1; $i<100; $i++){
        $arr[] = "stackoverflow".$i;
    }

    var_dump($arr);

?>
```

Comment: Please don't dump code-only answers into the site. The code is far less important than the explanation that is supposed to go with it.